# Lentidão ao gerar relatórios

Tags: php, mysql

Bem estou tendo alguns gargalos na minha aplicação e não estou identificando o problema.
Vou tentar explicar ao máximo o que acontece e a configuração que utilizo.

Configurações do servidor

Uso um servidor Jelastic com 2 ambientes. Um rodando o php 5.6 e o outro rodando o mysql 5.6.24.
Com isso tenho ambientes separados, melhorando a performance uma vez que cada servidor tem seu próprio processador e memória.

Configurações do site

O php executa uma query de consulta simples, porém o usuário tem muitos registros, que podem chegar na casa dos 20.000 registros por relatório. Logo este relatório leva algum tempo para ser finalizado porém sem nenhum problema.

Descrição do problema

Quando um usuário gera o relatório o mesmo leva em média de 1 a 3 minutos para ser finalizado, devido a grande quantidade de dados, porém todo o sistema fica lento, até mesmo para outras pessoas que não estão na mesma rede.
Todo o servidor demora a responder e a situação se normaliza somente após o término do processo de gerar o relatório.
O Jelastic fornece gráficos para acompanhar o consumo da memória e processador.
Acompanho eles mas a carga não chega nem a metade do que eu tenho configurado no meu ambiente, ou seja não parece ser problema de pouca memória ou processador.
Tem alga coisa que estou esquecendo de configurar ou verificar?
É possível fazer o sistema controlar os recursos para cada conexão (usuário) para que isso não ocorra mais?

———————————————————— Edit ————————————————

Bom para ficar mais fácil vou postar a forma que estou montando o relatório. O problema ocorre no back-end, quando estou montando o array.

1 º Tenho 3 tabelas, sendo elas:
`cadastro`,`f_pagamento` e `pedidos`.

2º Monto o array assim:

// Consulta no BD
    $consulta = $conexao->query("
        select 
            * 
        from 
            pedidos 
        where 
            data >= '01-07-2017'
            and  data <= '27-07-2017'
        ORDER BY 
            data DESC
    ");

```
// Lista resultados
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

    // Verifica se tem algum vendedor se não tiver coloca null no array
    if ($resultado->id_vendedor !== null) {

        // Consulta cadastro
        $consulta_vendedor = $conexao->query("select nome from cadastro where id = '$resultado->id_vendedor' LIMIT 1");
        $resultado_vendedor = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta_vendedor);
        $vendedor_nome = $resultado_vendedor->nome;
    } else {
        $vendedor_nome = null;
    }

    // Verifica se tem forma de pagamento se não tiver coloca null no array
    if ($resultado->id_pagamento !== null) {

        // Consulta forma de pagamento
        $consulta_forma = $conexao->query("select forma from f_pagamento where id = '$resultado->id_pagamento' LIMIT 1");
        $resultado_forma = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta_forma);
        $nome_forma = $resultado_forma->forma;
    } else {
        $nome_forma = null;
    }

    // Verifica se tem cliente se não tiver coloca null no array
    if ($resultado->id_cliente !== null) {

        // Consulta nome do cliente
        $consulta_cliente = $conexao->query("select nome from cadastro where id = '$resultado->id_cliente' LIMIT 1");
        $resultado_cliente = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta_cliente);
        $nome_cliente = $resultado_cliente->nome;
    } else {
        $nome_cliente = null;
    }

   // Inicia variáveis
    $total = 0;

    // Consulta os produtos no pedido
    $consulta = Query($mysqli, "select valor,qtd from produtos_pedidos where id_pedido = '$resultado->id'");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

        // Calculo
        $total += $resultado->qtd * $resultado->valor;
    }


    // Array com dados dos produtos
    $pedidos[] = array(
        "id" => $resultado->id,
        "folha_pg" => $resultado->id_folha_pagamento,
        "vendedor" => $vendedor_nome,
        "cliente" => $nome_cliente,
        "data" => $resultado->data,
        "forma_pg" => $nome_forma,
        “total” => $total
    );  
}
```

OBS: O resultado é em torno de uns 20.000 pedidos.

A tabela `cadastro` tem cerca de uns 3.600 registros
A tabela `f_pagamento` tem cerca de uns 100 registros
A tabela `pedidos` tem cerca de uns 50.00 registros porém estou filtrando apenas os resultados de 1 mês.
A tabela `produtos_pedidos` tem em média 10 produtos para cada pedido

Notei que de eu remover o campo total do array o relatório não trava, fica lento mais não trava. Então o problema deve estar nessa parte:

```
   // Inicia variáveis
    $total = 0;

    // Consulta os produtos no pedido
    $consulta = Query($mysqli, "select valor,qtd from produtos_pedidos where id_pedido = '$resultado->id'");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

        // Calculo
        $total += $resultado->qtd * $resultado->valor;
    }
```

Comment: Será não sua consulta não poderia ser otimizada, Indexes, etc ?

Comment: O problema e que mesmo assim, tenho que evitar que o sistema fique lento para todo mundo, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Posta aqui sua query. Talvez nao seja problema de processador / memoria mas sim a otimazação da query. 20k de resultados era para o MySQL tirar de letra

Comment: Outra pergunta, seu programa faz uma conexão para trazer esses 20k de resultados ou ele acessa um por um?

Comment: Uso apenas uma conexa, e por ela passo a query.

Comment: Sua consulta faz algum JOIN?

Comment: Não, vou postar minha query aqui manhã cedo.

Comment: @BrunoFolle editei minha pergunta com um exemplo completo da query e do código em php, se puder me ajudar irei ficar muito grato. Obrigado.

Comment: O problema "é e não é a query". Tive um problema parecido para montar um relatorio num site em produção. Cada laço do seu while ele consulta uma vez no banco, ou seja, se sua primeira consulta tiver 20k de resultados, ele irá fazer 20k de consultas na suas tables. É isso que ta pesando para fazer o seu relatório. Já tentou ou pensou em utlizar Join, left join e right join?

Comment: A comunicação do PHP com o mysql quando há varias consultas assim como a sua, tendem a ser um problema pois a resposta entre os dois é meio lenta e acaba travando ou tirando o sql do ar. O que fiz para contornar esse problema no meu caso, foi fazer uma query retornar todos os dados necessários e depois arrumar esses dados via PHP. Deu trabalho, mas ficou super rápido.

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar procedure http://www.devmedia.com.br/stored-procedures-no-mysql/29030